# I want hide Add New Customer button for specific admin roles

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, magento2.3

I want to hide `"ADD NEW CUSTOMER"` button on customer_grid page for certain admin roles, how to specify Specify ACL's for ui_components..?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add" class="SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Customer\AddButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Ui/Customer/AddButton.php

Change **Magento_Cms::save** to your new role

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Ui\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class AddButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Url Builder
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * AddButton constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $context->getUrlBuilder();
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Cms::save')) {
            return [];
        }

        return [
            'label' => __('Add New Customer'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('*/*/new')),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Magento_Cms ..?

Comment: You change this Magento_Cms::save to your role id, that I already said. I tested using that in my local.

Comment: I don't know what is your role, so create new one acl.xml, and change here

Comment: okay, are you able to hide that button for different role other than admin..?

Comment: yes, why not. Did you try that?

Comment: yes it didn't work :(, i am using B2B which has Company-module in it, i want to hide "New company" button also

Comment: After changing role from admin, you need to login again.

Comment: How I test? Create new role that has only customer access. Assign that role for testing user. So this button should not visible because I use here for Magento_Cms::save (which is cms save) And it works.

Comment: Check carefully this is working code, You defenitely make some mistake in your end.

Comment: okay, i am checking were i made mistake.

Comment: i double check everything, but it's not working for me, am using magento B2B feature v2.2.2

Comment: Hi @Sohel, can you help me out getting this thing done on my side, can you share the acl.xml how you defined, am not getting it i tried in different ways.

Comment: Check how magento declare Magento_Cms::save in CMS module.

Comment: @Sohel could u please guide me too. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267057/disable-button-for-certain-user-groups-roles.